# mysql login with -p password fails

Tags: mysql

I am trying to login to mysql with -p option. The login succeeds when mysql prompts me to Enter the password.

```
mysql -uuser -p
Enter Password: pass (Login succeeds)
```

But, When i try to enter the password with -p option it fails

```
mysql -uuser -ppass 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Any idea on why this happens?

Comment: I thought it was `-u user -p pass`?

Comment: I picked a random username(user) & password(pass) for the question..

Answer (score 1):

Quite possible your password has a character in it that's being interpreted as something else by the shell (maybe globbing)?  Try `-p'pass'`